# post web page to php

Tags: php, ajax, post

I want to post a whole page using ajax to php file to be parsed.

say the sources is `http://www.mysite.com/page-1.

now post this page (from `<html> to </html>`) to "parse-page.php". and retrieve it with $_POST['document'].

Comment: Do you already use a javascript framework like jQuery?

Comment: How come you want to do this? Is there any reason you couldn't just pass the address and use the php to read it?

Comment: @the JinX: yes, I know one way is "get" the html value of the document and send via ajax - but I don't want the code to break. I'm looking for a better alternative if there is any

Comment: @Jacob: Im adding dynamic html content to the webpage (using ajax). Now I could use file_get_contents() to parse the page but the dynamic content is not returned, in other words all I get is the webpage as it was when loaded -not after it was modified ONLINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you just want to post the data and ignore anything coming back from the php, this should work.

```
$.post("parse-page.php", {'document', $('body').html()});
```

For more info: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you can use javascript to store the innertext of the html tag and send that variable through ajax.